# НОК acmp задача 14

Tags: c++

Требуется написать программу, определяющую наименьшее общее кратное (НОК) чисел a b
Помогите с решением(минимальный тайм лимит)

Comment: И в чем проблема?... HOK(a,b) = a*b/НОД(a,b), а уж НОД ищется практически мгновенно... Покажите хотя бы ваши попытки.

Comment: Алгоритм Евклида и поехали.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: у меня было лобовое решение и были проблемы с тайм лимитом

Comment: Используйте кнопку править, чтобы добавить код

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Лови алгоритм Евклида:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cmath> 
using namespace std; 
int main(){ 
 long long a, b; 
cin » a » b; 
 long long c = a, d = b; 
while(b){ 
 a %= b; 
 swap(a, b); 
} 
cout « (c * d) / a; 
}
```

Comment: Минус от меня - за решение учебной задачи ("Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.")

Comment: Кстати, функция `gcd` - НОД - входит в стандарт С++, так что ее можно и не писать :) И учтите, что в вашем варианте - когда `c*d` в скобках - программа может не работать из-за переполнения этого произведения!